# Refactoring React class to hooks - Entity update component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have this React component that I use to update business entities. It basically fetches by ID on componentDidMount and sends a put request when the form is submitted. I would like to refactor this to a hook based component.

Here is the code before

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

//Api Helper Methods
const API_HOST = "https://api.example.com";
const get = (endPoint) =>
  axios
    .get(`${API_HOST}/${endPoint}`)
    .then((response) => response.data);

export const put = (endPoint, payload, id) =>
  axios
    .put(`${API_HOST}/${endPoint}/${id}`, payload)
    .then((response) => response.data);

//React route (uses React Router)
const END_POINT = `users`;

class Entity extends React.Component {

  state = { entity: {}, fetching: true };

  getEntity = async () => {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    this.setState({ fetching: true });
    const entity = await get(`${END_POINT}/${id}`);
    this.setState({ entity, fetching: false });
  };

  onChange = (key, value) =>
    this.setState({ entity: { ...this.state.entity, [key]: value } });

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getEntity();
  }

  onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let { entity } = this.state;
    let { match } = this.props;
    await put(END_POINT, entity, match.params.id);
  };

  render() {
    const { entity, fetching } = this.state;

    if (fetching) {
      return <p>loading...</p>;
    }

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="name">name</label>
        <input
          value={entity["name"]}
          onChange={(e) => this.onChange("name", e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Entity;
```

This is what I have so far for the code after. Next step would be to extract custom hook.

```
const END_POINT = `users`;

export default function Entity({ match }) {
  const [entity, setEntity] = useState({ name: "" });
  const [fetching, setFetching] = useState( true );
  const { id } = match.params;

  const onChange = (key, value) => setEntity({ ...entity, [key]: value });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchEntity = async () => {
      const entity = await get(`${END_POINT}/${id}`);
      setEntity(entity);
      setFetching(false);
    };
    fetchEntity();
  }, [id]);

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await put(END_POINT, entity, id);
  };

  if (fetching) {
    return <p>loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="name">name</label>
      <input
        value={entity["name"]}
        onChange={(e) => onChange("name", e.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to convert a class-based component to functional component and then use your own two custom hooks in it?

Comment: I mean achieving the same functionality with hook/s. I added the link to the hooks I created just to try providing some context. I do not necessarily want to use them. I believe ideally I would create one hook I would use to fetch and update entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help Harben, I got it working like this.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

//Api Helper Methods
const API_HOST = "https://api.example.com";

const get = (endPoint) =>
  axios.get(`${API_HOST}/${endPoint}`).then((response) => response.data);

export const put = (endPoint, payload, id) =>
  axios
    .put(`${API_HOST}/${endPoint}/${id}`, payload)
    .then((response) => response.data);


const END_POINT = `users`;

const useEntity = (entityId) => {
  const [entity, setEntity] = useState({ name: "" });
  const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        const entity = await get(`${END_POINT}/${entityId}`);
        setEntity(entity);
        setFetching(false);
    })();
  }, [entityId]);

  return [entity, fetching, setEntity];
};

//React route (uses React Router)
export default function Entity({ match }) {
  const { id } = match.params;
  const [entity, fetching, setEntity] = useEntity(id);

  const onChange = (key, value) => setEntity({ ...entity, [key]: value });

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await put(END_POINT, entity, id);
  };

  if (fetching) {
    return <p>loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="name">name</label>
      <input
        value={entity["name"]}
        onChange={(e) => onChange("name", e.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but this should be close to what you want with a custom hook for your entity function.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const API_HOST = "https://api.example.com";
const END_POINT = `users`;

function useEntity(entityID) {
    const [entity, setEntity] = useState({})
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            await fetch(`${API_HOST}/${END_POINT}/${props.match.params}`)
                .then(async res => await res.json())
                .then(result => setEntity(result));
        })();
    }, [])

    return entity
}

export default function Entity(props) {
    const { id } = props.match;
    const entity = useEntity(id);
    const onSubmit = async () => await fetch(`${API_HOST}/${END_POINT}/${id}`, {method: 'PUT', body: entity})

    if (!entity) {
        return <p>loading...</p>;
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="name">name</label>
            <input
            value={entity["name"]}
            onChange={(e) => setEntity({ ...entity, name: e.target.value})}
            />
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```